# Unable to retrieve li tags information

Tags: php, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

This website has a funny structure, I actually managed to get what I want using selenium, but upon trying the second time, I cannot get the data I want. This is how it goes:-

**1st Try** (Correct information):-
bank name list,
bank account and balance

**2nd Try** (Wrong information):-
bank transfer method,
bank name list

I notice the div is shifted to different position suddenly. I'm using this xpath to extract the information I want:-

```
//div[12]/div[1]/ul[1]/li['.$x.']
```

Now I want it to extract base on the div id, so I came up with this xpath:-

```
//*[@id="idBnk_panel"]//div/ul/following::li
```

but it can't work properly to extract the information I need. Any idea how to grab the information from the `li` tags based on this structure?

```
<div id="something_here">
    <div>
        <ul>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can test the xpath you think is correct from the browser first before using it on the code. In chrome or firefox open the console and write $x('//xpath/here') and it will return an element if the xpath path is correct which is highlighted so you can know if it is the one you wanted

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to extract all 3 `<li>` tag data . So here is the code for that -

```
    List<WebElement> element  =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='something_here']/div/ul/li"));
    for(WebElement iterate:element)
    {
        System.out.println(iterate.getText());
    }
```

Here I 've used `getText()` method, just get the text of `<li>` tag . You can manipulate according your requirement what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath you are using is incorrect
//*[@id="idBnk_panel"]//div/ul/following::li

The correct xpath as per the HTML you showed is
//div[@id='something_here']/div/ul/li[index_number_as_required]
or you can directly use
//div[@id='something_here']//li[index_number_as_required]

and then use String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@id='something_here']//li[index_number_as_required])).getText();

Answer (score 0):

If the xpath is changing time to time due to some dynamic data display, since the "id" of a div is available, you can use below code also.

```
List<WebElement> mainLabels = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
mainLabels = driver.findElement(By.id("something_here")).findElements(By.tagName("li"));
//mainLabels list contains all the li elements

//Then you can access the texts either this way
mainLabels.get(0).getText();//This will give you the text that is in first li
mainLabels.get(1).getText();//This will give you the text that is in second li

//OR this way
for (int i = 0; i < mainLabels.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(mainLabels.get(i).getText());
}
```